# PhpMailer Invalid address:(setFrom)

Tags: php, email, web, hosting, phpmailer

I don't know why it's not working. As far as i understand in some point my post request it's not been accepted ... so here is my code

```html
<meta charset="utf-8" type="text/html">

<?php
echo !extension_loaded('openssl')?"Not Available":"Available";
echo'<br>';
include 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$name = $_POST['nombre'];
$mailfrom = $_POST['email'];
$context = $_POST['context'];

echo $name,$mailfrom,$context;
echo "<br>";

echo "<br>";
$subject = 'Information';
/*i'm not sure if i can use any gmail or it needs to be
  registred on my server admin panel*/
$to ="my@gmail.com";
define ('GUSER','my@gmail.com');
define ('GPWD','pass');


// make a separate file and include this file in that. call this function in that file.

function smtpmailer( $mailfrom, $name, $subject, $context) {
    global $error;
    $mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
    $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
    $mail->Host = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";

    $mail->Username = GUSER;
    $mail->Password = GPWD;
    $mail->SetFrom ($mailfrom); //here it's my error
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $context;
    $mail->AddAddress('my@gmail.com');
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo;
        return false;
    } else {
        $error = 'Message sent!';
        return true;
    }
}
 smtpmailer();

  ?>
```

Other important things to mention. This are the setting my hosting provider gives me. And i'm not sure if i'm using them properly. I've tried with all ports and host, but just get the same error.

[smtp settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMWHp.png)

[ports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSLDo.png)

i really  appreciate all the help :)

Comment: setForm needs 2 arguments, first your mail address, second a text what discribes it. here a sample from the official homepage of phpmailer: `$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Your Name');` and you have to check if the content of $mailForm is realy a string and a valid mail address

Comment: tried still same error

Comment: No. The second parameter to `setFrom` is optional, and will return `false` if you provide an invalid address, so you don't need to check it in advance, just look at its return value.

Comment: @Eduardo Rawrdríguez when you call the function ` smtpmailer(); ` You need to pass 4 arguments like this ` smtpmailer( $mailfrom, $name, $subject, $context); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
include 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

define ('GUSER','my@gmail.com');
define ('GPWD','pass');

$name       = $_POST['nombre'];
$mailfrom   = $_POST['email'];
$context    = $_POST['context'];

$subject    = 'Information';
$to         = "my@gmail.com";

smtpmailer($mailfrom, $name, $subject, $context);


// make a separate file and include this file in that. call this function in that file.

function smtpmailer($from, $name, $subject, $context) {
    global $error;
    $mail = new PHPMailer();                    // create a new object

    $mail->isSMTP();                            // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host      = 'smtp.gmail.com';        // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth  = true;                    // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->CharSet   = "UTF-8";
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                       // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isHTML(true);                        // Set email format to HTML
    
    
    $mail->Username = GUSER;                    // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = GPWD;                     // SMTP password
    
    //$mail->SMTPAutoTLS    = false;
    $mail->SMTPSecure   = 'tls';                // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port         = 587;                  // TCP port to connect to

    $mail->setFrom($from,$name);            // Mail Form
    $mail->addAddress('my@gmail.com');          // Name is optional

    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body    = $context;
    
   if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo;
        return false;
    } else {
        $error = 'Message sent!';
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Eduardo Rawrdríguez If this code not work You need to first logout all gmail then login your mail that you use at CONSTANT variable `GUSER` then goto this link: [click here](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) change this: Allow less secure apps: OFF to  Allow less secure apps: ON. Then try again to send mail.

Comment: Yes i tried all you said, still no getting mails.  Actually my acount syncronized with my phone to verify ... but still nothing u,u

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this:

```
$mailfrom = $_POST['email'];
...
$mail->SetFrom($mailfrom);
```

Even if `$mailfrom` is a valid address, this is forgery and your messages will fail SPF checks and either be bounced or end up in spam folders. This is why the PHPMailer docs and examples tell you not to do this.

The second parameter is entirely optional; the main advantage of calling `setFrom` over setting `From` directly is that it validates the address immediately so that you don't need to wait until trying to send to find out.

Also, you're sending through gmail, which will not allow you to send from arbitrary addresses, only predefined aliases, so it just won't work anyway.

The right way to do this is:

```
$mail->setFrom('my@gmail.com');
if (!$mail->addReplyTo($mailfrom)) {
    echo 'Invalid email address';
    exit;
}
```

You're also setting your `Host` value with `$mail->Host = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';` while also setting `SMTPSecure = 'tls'`; this is incompatible and will not work. Set `Host` to just plain `smtp.gmail.com`.

It would have been a whole load easier if you had used the gmail example provided with PHPMailer that avoids all these issues.

Comment: ok , so i tried it and and it's supposedto work. At least it's no sending me any error, but neither sending any mail. D: